# How to send a notification only if the order has been completed in WooCommerce Gravity Forms Product Addon

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I use the WooCommerce Gravity Forms Product Addon plugin.

I want to send a notification only if the product order in Woocommerce has been paid and the order status is completed. By default, notifications will be sent if there are new entries in Gravity Forms (events form_submission).

The problem is, I have not succeeded in making a trigger so that the notification will be sent when the payment status is "completed". I don't know which action I use and can be integrated with entries in Gravity Forms so that notifications are sent according to the data.

I have made a notification in Gravity Form with custom events, I named it "completed".

This is the code for adding these custom events.

```
add_filter( 'gform_notification_events', 'add_event_completed' );
function add_event_completed( $notification_events ) {
    $notification_events['completed'] = __( 'Payment Completed', 'gravityforms' );
    return $notification_events;
}
```

I used a reference from https://docs.gravityforms.com/send-notifications-on-payment-events/ to try to make an action hook so that notifications were sent when the order in Woocommerce was paid. But there are no notifications sent.

```
add_action( 'gform_post_payment_action', function ( $entry, $action ) {
    $form = GFAPI::get_form( $entry['form_id'] );
    GFAPI::send_notifications( $form, $entry, rgar( $action, 'type' ) );
}, 10, 2 );
```

I have confirmed that if the notifications are set using "form_submission" events, the notification can be sent.

I want to send a notification only if the product order in Woocommerce has been paid and the order status is completed.

**UPDATE**

I have found a solution, but still use dirty methods. So after reverse engineering, I hacked the plugin code so that the plugin can do what I want.

I added the following code to the gravityforms-product-addons-entry.php file in line 218. In that section, the plugin will update entries in Gravity Forms when payment in Woocommerce has been made. So I give a filter if the payment status has been "completed", it will send a notification.

```
// Kirim Notifikasi Sudah Lunas
// gravityforms-product-addons-entry.php
// Line 218

if ($the_order->get_status() == "completed"){
  $form  = GFAPI::get_form( $form_data['id'] );
  $entry = GFAPI::get_entry( $entry_id );

  GFAPI::send_notifications( $form, $entry, 'completed' );
}
```

Of course this method is not feasible to apply in the future, please enlighten me to make a snippet that I can put in the function.php file.

Thank you.